# Checking if user is authenticated in every page in asp net

Tags: c#, webforms

I have been using FormsAuthentication and I've been using this code in every single page and masterpage on Page_load

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || Session["Nome"] == null)
{
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
}
```

However I feel like i shouldn't do this 'cause i don't know why, i get redirected to login page for no reason before session expiration time.

So the point is... Do I need to check somehow if user is authenticated on codebehind if i'm using formsauthentication defined in web config already?

Comment: Forms authentication is designed so you can configure it completely in web.config. I would look at your session value `Nome` as the issue if you are redirected unexpectedly.

Comment: I see, i completly forgot about the authorization part in web config. I guess it must be the session is not being updated fast enough and it reads null at some point